# AutoMapper 9.x how to update on existing entity object

Tags: c#, automapper, aspnetboilerplate

I try to move my project to AutoMapper 9.x but I don't find a solution to update an object read from EF.

The situation is like as describe on this old post [Using Automapper to update an existing Entity POCO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314666/using-automapper-to-update-an-existing-entity-poco)

The big issue is that:
AutoMapper 9.x has removed the static Mapper.Map and you can add the [AutoMap(typeof(x))] attribute but it solve the mapping from EF Class to DTO class.

```cs
class MyPoco{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

[AutoMap(typeof(MyPoco))]
public class Customer {
    public int Id { get;set; }
}

    MYPOCO pocoDesc= dbContext.DD_POCO.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == 123);
    //Row below not supported
    AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Customer, MYPOCO>(customerSrc, pocoDesc);
    dbContext.Save();
```

At the moment the only way to solve is remove AutoMapper and manually bind one by one the property.

UPDATE

After some test I try to compare to call

```
ObjectMapper.Map(input.Article, article);
        Mapper.Instance.Map(input.Article, article);
```

ObjectMapper came from DI. In startup module I register via IMapperConfigurationExpression

```cs
    mapper.CreateMap<Customer,MyPoco>().ConvertUsing((src,dto) =>{
// remove for brevity
});
```

And I see that static API not pass throw my custom map opposite to ObjectMapper that use my custom map. At the moment I don't understand why but I try to investigate more

Comment: Rather than use the static Mapper.Map, the preferred way is to use Dependency Injection and inject the Mapper in to services that need it.

Comment: Static mappings where never needed to map EF classes. Just inject the mapper instance, the same way you inject the `dbContext`, or create your own singleton instance of the mapper, eg `static class MyMapper{  static MyMapper(){/*initialize here*/} public static Mapper {get; private set;} }`. The *correct* solution though is to use dependency injection

Comment: What does your code look like, specifically the methods that use the mapper and their classes? How do you pass dependencies to them? If you want a specific answer this matters. In an .NET Core project for example, DI is a standard feature. In ASP.NET MVC the code you'd need to inject the mapper depends on the actual DI container you use.

Comment: My project is based on Asp.net Boilerplate v 4.8.1 (and the framework use Castle for DI).  So if I correct understand the suggestion is use IMapper inject via DI (in my case I can use ObjectMapper that do exact via DI) in place of Mapper.Map?

Comment: That's the idea :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thanks for the clarification