# Automapper : mapping with child class trouble DynamicProxies

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

```
public class MyClassA
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }

    int MyClassBId { get; set; }
    int MyClassCId { get; set; }
}

public class MyClassB
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyClassC
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I do a join :

```
using (var context = GetNewContext())
{
    var liste =
        (from myA in context.MyClassA
         join myB in context.MyClassB on myA.MyClassBId equals myB.Id
         join myC in context.MyClassC on myA.MyClassCId equals myC.Id
         select MyClassA).ToList<MyClassA>();

    return Mapper.Map<IList<MyClassA>, List<MyOtherClassA>>(liste);
}
```

I get this exception on the return :

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
_FB2F4E3BBB925EC65C0AE58F6566366E06009C68B4A2C1C12EE401E77A489D87 -> IMyClassB
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SITE_FB2F4E3BBB925EC65C0AE58F6566366E06009C68B4A2C1C12EE401E77A489D87
```

The mapping is :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyClassA, MyOtherClassA>()
    .ForMember(x => x.MyClassB, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(x => x.MyClassC, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Other problem(?) ... when I try to insert, I have to do this :

```
var newA = Mapper.Map<MyOtherClassA, MyClassA>(newA);
newA.MyClassB = null;
newA.MyClassC = null;

context.MyClassA.Add(newA);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This looks like the same problem as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416816/how-to-update-an-existing-entity-from-viewmodel-using-automapper-and-ef4-dbconte) and also have a look at SubKamrans answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441916/automapper-mapping-issue-with-inheritance-and-abstract-base-class-on-collectio)

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441916/automapper-mapping-issue-with-inheritance-and-abstract-base-class-on-collectio , the similar issue.

Comment: Just a thought, are you writing out your POCO proxy classes and Mapping yourself? Are you aware of the DbContext Generator that will generate your POCO's for you and have EF handle the mapping internally? http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7812b04c-db36-4817-8a84-e73c452410a2

Comment: @coding-ninja: this generator is intended for *model-first* approach, *code-first* approach means writing entity classes and (possibly), mappings manually. In addition, how your comment is related to question?

Comment: What is `MyOtherClassA`? (Is it the same as `MyClassA` or does it have different properties?)