# Mapping two arrays with automapper return empty array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I'm trying to Map with Automapper two arrays, the soure is a poco object from EF and the destination my entity object, that's what I have done and allways return an Empty Array:

From Log[] To > Model.Log[]

```
   var srcLog = db.Set<Log>().Where(e => e.Id > id).Take(quantity).ToArray();
   var result = Mapper.DynamicMap<Log[], Model.Log[]>(srcLog);
```

EF Log object:

```
 public partial class Log
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Member_Id { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }       
        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
    }
```

Model.Log[] object:

```
 public class Log
    {
        public long Id { get; set; } 
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public Member Member { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: And srcLog is not empty?

Comment: no, is not empty :( I was using Mapper.Map but I had problems with the property getType(), and then I changed it to DynamicMap and works fine for one item, but with one array is not working...

Comment: What properties do you have in `Log` and `Model.Log` types? Do they match?

Comment: Yes they match! Mapping one object works fine,

Comment: @user1520494 have you seen my answer or is there a stray neutrino ?

Comment: Hi Wal! yes, thanks for your response I was trying to do what you said, but I'm having problems with Mapper.Map,

Comment: what problems? that test compiles and passes...

Comment: Yes, That's the error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441916/automapper-mapping-issue-with-inheritance-and-abstract-base-class-on-collectio

Comment: Why are you using DynamicMap? This is only reserved for when you don't know the types at compile-time.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, I'm using Dynamic Map because I had problems mapping EF poco objects to my entities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a `Log[]` array mapping - instead just define the mapping between the 2 entities:

```
var srcLog = new[] {new Log {Id = 1}, new Log {Id = 2}};
Mapper.CreateMap<Log, Model.Log>();//do not map from/to an array

var result = Mapper.Map<Model.Log[]>(srcLog);
Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Length);
Assert.AreEqual(1, result[0].Id);
Assert.AreEqual(2, result[1].Id);//all green!
```

Doesnt appear you can use the generic or non generic `DynamicMap` however as you know the types at compile time you should use `CreateMap` anyway. see [here](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/04/15/automapper-feature-interfaces-and-dynamic-mapping/) for more details